# The word younger with aunt

Tags: word-usage

I want to talk about one of my father's sister comparing her with her elder sister, how do I define her age? Supposing that my father has three sisters, all younger than him. Now I want to talk about the sister who is the youngest I say:

> My youngest aunt is a doctor.

But if I want to talk about his sister who is on the second number in sisters, can I say:

> My younger aunt is a doctor.

Using the word 'younger' here would possibly give the impression that the aunt is younger than me, wouldn't it?

Comment: No, *younger*, *older*, and *elder* before a relationship category is idiomatically almost a title. Your younger aunt is your aunt who was born after your only other aunt.

Comment: The second sibling of three is usually called the *middle* child, so you could call her your 'middle aunt'.

Comment: I don’t believe any of the alternatives offered so far adequately embrace the meaning you need. Native English speakers would not reliably understand what you meant without already knowing there were three aunts. It is simply “not a thing” to refer to aunts this way. You would need to give a full explanation, such as: “I have three aunts and the middle one is a doctor.” Or “My aunt, the middle sister of three, is a doctor.”